# Empty Cart Redirect to Specific Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to redirect to page with URL slug 'join' or post-id 471, what should I put behind wc_get_page_id?

```
add_action("template_redirect", 'redirection_function');
function redirection_function(){
    global $woocommerce;
    if( is_cart() && WC()->cart->cart_contents_count == 0){
       wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'join' ) ) ); 
     exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'cart_empty_redirect_to_join' );
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to replace in your code `wc_get_page_id( 'join' )` by `471`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it in the following way.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'ani_empty_cart_redirect' );
function ani_empty_cart_redirect(){
    $page_id = 602; // Here you can add the ID of the page you want
    if( is_cart() && WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
        wp_safe_redirect(get_permalink($page_id));
        exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work. Let me know.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_if_empty_cart' );
function redirect_if_empty_cart() {

    if ( !is_cart() ) return;
    global $woocommerce;

    if( is_cart() && $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count == 0) {
        wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink( 471 ) );
        exit;
    }
    
}
```